# JavaScript: How to get quantity of elements by class

Tags: javascript

I have a number of divs with some class e.g. class="product". I need to get total quantity of elements with this class on a page by JavaScript-function that works by body onmouseover="some();". I need a solution only on JavaScript NOT on jQuery and NOT by document.querySelectorAll. I try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function some() {
  var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
  for(var i in product) {
    var quantity = product[i].length;
  }
}
</script>
<body onmouseover="some();">
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product"></div>
</body>
```

but it doesn't work. I need to get '2'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your html as well...?

Comment: HTMLElements don't have a `length` property. Do you want the number of `product` elements? `document.getElementsByClassName('product').length`?

Comment: Calling this function on mouseover is not a good idea.

Comment: Read what `getElementsByClassName` does first...it returns an array (well, HTMLCollection actually) of elements. And what do you do? Instead of get **this array's length** you're iterating over every **property** (no, not an element) of this array and try to get the lengths of **every property** instead of array's as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function some() {
  var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('product').length;
}
```